# SSJS using NULL values in Lookup

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

```
var src_table = DataExtension.Init("test_customers");
var unhashed_dataset = src_table.Rows.Lookup(["md5_email"], [null], 50);
```

I want to retreive rows where md5_email is empty or null.

I tried `[""]`, `[NULL]`, `NULL`... nothing is working. Sorry I'm new to SSJS....

BTW, is there any useful documentation besides 404 pages on SFMC help section?